# Non-apple USB mouse tracking slowly

Tags: usb, mouse

This morning my (non-apple) USB mouse, a HyperX PulseFire, has suddenly started tracking slowly.

I've checked the mouse preferences and nothing has changed since Friday. I've also increased the tracking to max and it doesn't change.

I've done the reset where I hold down `cmd + opt + p + r` and no change.

I've manually increased the scaling and tracking to 5.0 and 15.0 respectively using the terminal commands below and no change.

```
defaults write -g com.apple.mouse.scaling 5.0
defaults write -g com.apple.mouse.tracking 15.0
```

I'm now out of ideas - anyone experienced something like this before?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried increasing the DPI setting?

> The mouse's DPI setting is adjustable through the home-plate-shaped button behind the scroll wheel.

[Source](https://techreport.com/review/31781/hyperx-pulsefire-gaming-mouse-reviewed)

Comment: Doh!  Now I feel daft - this was the problem and I now feel very embarrassed ;-). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please don't feel embarrassed! The fact you've asked the question and have an answer means this will no doubt help other users too! :)